# How to limit execution time in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, execution-time

I have following code to limit execution time in MySQL but it is not working.
Someone help me out.

```
delimiter //
   CREATE PROCEDURE `classicWatches`.kill_long_running_queries()

BEGIN
  DECLARE process_id BIGINT;
  DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE kill_process_id CURSOR FOR SELECT ID FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE COMMAND = 'Query' AND TIME > 5; # only for 5 seconds just testing whether it works or not
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
  OPEN kill_process_query;

  loop_loop: LOOP

FETCH kill_process_id INTO process_id;   

IF process_id >=1 THEN 
    KILL QUERY process_id ; # Here showing error in mysql workbench but don't know what error
END IF ;
IF finished THEN

  LEAVE loop_loop;
END IF;
  END LOOP loop_loop;
     CLOSE kill_process_id;

END //
delimiter ;

CREATE EVENT kill_long_running_queries
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND
DO CALL `classicWatches`.kill_long_running_queries();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to accomplish.

[image]
The error shown in Workbench is because an integer is expected (as shown on line 23 - line 23 is just an example), but it is found `process_id` variable, however, the stored procedure is created and executed correctly when invoked.

[image]
The cursor is `kill_process_id`, but on line 13 you open the cursor `kill_process_query` does not exist, you need to change for line 14.

Comment: I want to kill all  processes which are taking more time .Suppose that process p 1 taking time more than  max time limit . then it should be kill automatically.

Comment: @SRSharma: You can use `KILL CONNECTION` or `KILL QUERY` depending on what you want to achieve. See [13.7.6.4 KILL Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/kill.html).

Comment: I want to kill the query but I don't know  what wrong with this code. Can you correct it If you can?

Comment: @SRSharma: Stored procedure with the indicated changes does the job you need.